# Blazor WASM - Lottie animation (lottie player) dont update after route change

Tags: routes, blazor, blazor-webassembly, lottie

I am trying to load lottie animations after every click of the button. I chose to not load animation itself but rather use routing. So every click will create a route localhost/1 -> it should load 1.json (lottie animation), localhost/2 -> it should load 2.json etc.

The problem is that I tried to use every lifecycle and also statehaschanged but nothing helped to change the lottie animation even if parameter is passing correctly.

So when you change route from "/" to "/2" the animation loads correctly but changing it then from "/2" to "/3" etc. doesnt work and animation even if its changed in the background(3.json) it will still show only 2nd one (2.json).

here is a code:

```
@page "/{animNumber:int}"
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
@inject NavigationManager navigationManager

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h3>Anim @animNumber</h3>
<lottie-player src="lottie/@(animNumber).json" background="transparent" speed="1" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;" loop autoplay></lottie-player>
<audio id="roar" src="/sound/duo.mp3" @onended="NavigateToNextAnimation" />
<button id="soundButton" @onclick="PlaySound">Click me!</button>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int animNumber { get; set; }

    public async Task PlaySound()
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("PlayAudio", "roar");
        animNumber++;
    }
    public void NavigateToNextAnimation()
    {
        navigationManager.NavigateTo($"/{animNumber}");
    }
}
```

here is a repo:
https://github.com/Laftek/BlazorNotReloadingLottie.git

Thank you.

I tried the steps above but it didnt work.